# how to Concatenated error message to bad file from sql ldr

Tags: oracle, shell, unix, sql-loader

I have a csv file test.csv, i am loading this through sqlloader which is called in shell script to a table test. if there is any error .bad file will be generated in unix directories.

the table test structure as a number(10), b varchar2(1), c date(DD/MM/YYYY).

While loading if there is any data type err test.bad file will be generated along with log file.

Log file will have the exact error message.

Now let's say in test.csv  row_num=1 got redirected to test.bad file then i need to incorporate the error message as well to the end of the line , which is been writen to the log file.

E.G. 100,A,1,C is not a DATE.

how can i achive this? please help .

Answer (score 0):

Define an  [external table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/et_concepts.htm) with all columns as VARCHAR2 and point it to the BAD file.
Add the error information (e.g. 'bad record A= xx,...') to a new column and UNION ALL it with the original table.

Comment: As of now the batch loading the data just i need to add the functionality to add the error_mesaage which is there in log_file to .bad file.The solution which you proposed is not feasible.

Comment: @ user3195273 added modified solution with extrernal table on teh bad file